# Intermediate Value Property non-strict inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be a function that has the intermediate value property on $[a,b]$, that is, if $[x,y] \subseteq [a,b]$ and $L$ is such that $f(x) < L < f(y)$ or $f(y) < L < f(x)$ then there exists a $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f(c)=L$.

Now, in the definition above, $L$ is strictly between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, i.e., $L$ cannot be equal to $f(x)$ or $f(y)$. So, what if I picked an $L$ such that $f(y) < L \le f(x)$, does this imply that there exists a $c \in [x, y)$ such that $f(c)=L$? If so, why?

Comment: If $L$ were $f(x)$, you can just pick $c=x$

Comment: Oh true, so what if I had $f(y) \le L \le f(x)$, can I still claim there exists a $c \in (x,y)$ such that $f(c) = L$?

Comment: No, think about $f_{\pm}(x)=\pm x$